# positioning a div outside another div

Tags: css, html, position

I have a div that is centered using `margin: 0 auto; display: table;`. The `div` is `960px` wide.

There is another div inside this one. It is a search box and it is left-aligned in the top corner. But I would like this div to be left-aligned to the very left side of the browser window, meaning it would be visually outside or inside the main centered div depending on the browser window size. 
Is there a way to achieve this in CSS?

Comment: `position:absolute;top:0;left:0` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `position:absolute; left:0px;` on the search box. See my jsfiddl (the container ID has shrunk so that it could fit in the JsFiddle window, but the concept should be sound): http://jsfiddle.net/CQ9cc/.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was trying to do it and it was not working. After asking the question here and getting it confirmed, I again tried it and found the divs I needed to apply this to in Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/5qT3p/

this would be the code:

```
#container{
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
width:400px;
height:300px;
background:#111;
}


#searchbox{
position:absolute;
height:20px;
width:100px;
background:#f1f1f1;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was trying to do it this way before but due to the amount of enclosed divs in Drupal it was difficult to apply this solution. But now I managed to apply it to the right div and it worked.